# ES6 import of multiple files with key identifiers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack-4

I am trying to import a module that could be associated with multiple files depending on conditionals. I originally had that being imported using a require dynamically through a "const" as so:

```
const question_pack_requires = {};
require.context('../question-packs/section-2', true, /^(.*\.(js$))[^.]*$/im).keys()
  .forEach(async (key) => {
    const name = path.normalize(key).replace('.js', '');

    // THIS IS THE PROMISE-BASED (ASYNC / AWAIT) WEBPACK DYNAMIC IMPORT SYNTAX

    const questionPack = await import(`../question-packs/section-2/${name}`);
    question_pack_requires[name] = questionPack;
  });

export default question_pack_requires;
```

However, this has broken when upgrading to Webpack 4 and now is throwing a Type Error. So was planning on just importing each of these manually and assigning a key to each one, however, I am unsure the syntax on how to do that.

Basically I need to convert this "require" to an "import" or import these files manually one by one. s there anyone that can help guide me in the best way to do that?

Comment: FYI, I don't think you can do conditional `import` yet (like you can with `require()`).  Right now, `import` must be at the top level and not inside a conditional.  Those working on the implementation and standard are apparently working on how that should eventually work.

Comment: The conditional I am talking about is a separate function later that depending on what the user selected, it will load the appropriate module. However, it can't do that if the modules aren't imported first and the Type Error I was talking about I think is happening cause there is no value for 'question_pack_requires'. So I need to import those modules but under on name with some kind of unique identifier key. Is there a way to do that?